# Does Athene's Unholy Grail's passive proc on minion kills?

Tags: league-of-legends

The passive says:

*Restores 12% of your max mana on kill or assist.*

Does it means *champion* kill or assists or *any* kill or assists (including minion and monster kills)?

Comment: Generally when an item description mentions the term "kill or assist", it refers to champion kills or assists (as they don't count "assists" for minion kills). "Kill" by itself, however, can be more ambiguous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Champion kill or assist. You can read full details about the item [here.](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Athene%27s_Unholy_Grail)